# python: чтение строк и работа с каждой из строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Всем привет! Мне необходима работа со строками из файла. У меня есть файл `bonus.py`, в нем содержится:

```
1
2
3
```

И есть файл `test.py`, в нем содержится:

```
import bonus
file = open('c://testper/bonus.py', 'r')
qwe = file.readlines()
print(qwe) # для считывания строк, что там вообще содержится
if qwe == '1':
    print('Sucs!(1)')
else:
    print('error')
```

Он выводит *error*, так как не обнаружил в файле `bonus.py` цифру 1. В `print(qwe)` выводится:

> ['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']

Как сделать так, чтобы он читал ВСЕ строки, и в строках искал то число, которое необходимо для вывода 'Sucs(1)'?

Comment: изменил file.readlines() на file.read() - в print(qwe) выводит: 1 2 3 (по каждой строке), но всё равно вылазит ошибка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Так как в файле bonus.py находятся цифры: 1, 2, 3, где каждая с новой строки, следовательно в списке 'qwe' после каждой цифры стоит '\n', '\n' обозначает перенос на след. строчку.
2. В этой строчке `if qwe == '1':` вы сравниваете список со строкой, а не строку со строкой.

Вот один из вариантов решения:

```
import bonus

file = open(r'c://testper/bonus.py', 'r')
qwe = file.readlines()
print(qwe) # для считывания строк, что там вообще содержится
if '1\n' in qwe:
    print('Sucs!(1)')
else:
    print('error')
```

Вот еще более удобный:

```
import bonus
file = open(r'C:\Users\mihai\.spyder-py3/bonus.py', 'r')
qwe = [x.strip() for x in file.readlines()] # убираем '\n'
print(qwe) # для считывания строк, что там вообще содержится
if '1' in qwe:
    print('Sucs!(1)')
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что)) Я написал еще один более удобнее вариант

Comment: а не поможете случайно решить проблему при удалении строки? если не трудно, есть переменная ert = f'\n{message.chat.id}' (она равна айди)
и метод del, я приписал к этому методу переменную ert, - del ert но эта строка не удаляется, хотя она там есть

Comment: @str Для списков используйте метод 'remove'(Например: qwe.remove('1')), также все методы списков вы можете найти здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html